# Auto-completion puts back-slash before $ mark, how can I disable it? (ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: command-line, bash, 22.04, environment-variables, auto-completion

To access files in a directory from another directory, I often set a variable for that directory. For example (so you can try it your self),

> export dir1=/usr/local/bin

and then type `ls $dir1/` followed by `tab`. I wanted the shell to show the files under /usr/local/bin but by the `tab`, the character `$` is escaped with `\` to become `\$dir1` and the shell doesn't understand it as `$dir1` anymore and doesn't expand it to /usr/local/bin not showing the files there. This is quite annoying (I used to do these things with no problem before but is it happening from ubuntu-22.04?). Is there any way I can stop this auto escaping during the file name auto completion?
p.s. - I saw https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-02/msg00280.html but found no answer, just non essential long discussions that are not to the point..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is controlled by the `direxpand` shell option:

> direxpand
>
> If set, Bash replaces directory names with the results of word expansion when performing filename completion. This changes the
> contents of the Readline editing buffer. If not set, Bash attempts to
> preserve what the user typed.

So check if the option is set in your shell (`shopt direxpand`) and if not, set it with `shopt -s direxpand`.

See

- [How to expand filenames with Tab, even when a shell variable is used in the path?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/378625/65304)
- [The shopt builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#index-shopt)

Comment: It works OK on my system: `direxpand` is off, Ubuntu 23.10, and bash  version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)